# How to use simple_fields_for to create many objects of the same nested type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, simple-form

I have the following in my model:

```
company.rb

 has_many :merits
 accepts_nested_attributes_for  :merits
```

In my Controller:

```
def new
   @company = Company.new
   @company.merits.build
 end
```

On my form:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

  = f.simple_fields_for :merits do |m|
    = m.input :description, :required => false
    = m.input :picture, :required => false
```

This produces a hash as follows:

.`.."merits_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"description"=>"stove", "picture"=>"www.it.com/stove.png"}}...`

What I want to have is multiple objects as follows:

..."merits_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"description"=>"stove", "picture"=>"www.it.com/stove.png"},"1"=>{"description"=>"fridge", "picture"=>"www.it.com/fridge.png"}}...

Can I do this, how can I do this and if so in the controller will it create multiple objects using :

```
def create
 @company = Company.new(params[:company])
      if @company.save
        sign_in @company
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render :new

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want several `merits` on your form just build the same number of merits in your controller:

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  3.times { @company.merits.build } # will build 3 merits
end
```

Comment: Does simple_fields_for have a standard mechanism to do this with an arbitrary number of fields using javascript?

Comment: @olleicua - No. Try using the cocoon gem.